# A group, whose reflected elements are not a group

Tags: calculus, group-theory, functions

The following equation generates solutions, which can be viewed as elements of a group:

$$ \phi_{n,s}(x_n)=n^{\frac{s^2}{\log_n(x_n)}}=x_n.$$

Solving for $x_n$ gives:

$$ x_n=\frac{1}{n^s},n^s; $$

for $0<x<1,$ and $x>1,$ respectively.

This group under multiplication is comprised of elements: $E=\{\frac{1}{n^s}\},$ and inverse elements: $I=\{ n^s\},$ for $n \in\Bbb N,$ $s \in \Bbb C.$ This group is closed under multiplication because taking any two elements and multiplying them gives another element in the group. For example, $\frac{1}{2^s}\times \frac{1}{3^s}=\frac{1}{6^s}.$ The identity element is $1.$ Multiplying any element by its corresponding inverse element results in the identity element.

The following equation generates solutions, but can these solutions form a group? It's basically the first group reflected across $x=1/2$ but when I multiply corresponding elements to their inverse elements I don't get the identity element. I'm confused. Am I doing something wrong? Can it be salvaged as a group?

$$\phi_{n,s}(1-x_n)=n^{\frac{s^2}{\log_n(1-x_n)}}=1-x_n.$$

Solving for $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n^s},1-n^s;$

for $0<x<1,$ and $x<1,$ respectively.

The elements are $E=\{ 1-\frac{1}{n^s}\}$ and the inverse elements are $I=\{1-n^s\}.$